# drag and drop html elements or editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, html-email

I have a basic html email builder created and uses just a standard WYSIWYG Editor.  I have seen the likes of Mail Chimp using a Drag and Drop interface now for dropping in elements - e.g. 2 columns with images in 1st and text in 2nd.

I would like to implement something similar if possible.

Is there any Drag and Drop editors out there I could build into my site to use.

Or if building myself (the basics of it just) where would be the best place to start - is there some javascript libraries which could be used or good demo's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend jQuery UI, which affords drop and drag with the 'Droppable' and 'Draggable' interactions, respectively.

If you're a real beginner - http://html5demos.com/drag - should get you started with HTML5 drag and drop, so you can get a basic understanding of how it works.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) to JQuery UI's Connect Lists

Answer (score 0):

i saw this editor today. maybe it helps

http://imperavi.com/redactor/

TJL